# Reading a text file which contains lots of url , one per line & downloading the urls

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import wget

f = open("pic.txt", "r")

for image_url in f:
    print(image_url)
    image_filename = wget.download(image_url)
    print('Image Successfully Downloaded:', image_url)
```

It can print all the URLs in the file, each url per line successfully but can not download.
But when I give each `image_url` hardcoded, then it can successfully download.

Comment: Can you please add some examples?

Comment: I added whole code here

Comment: @San of the file ("pic.txt")! Also you may be interested in the [requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Comment: probably because of new-line char. Try `image_filename = wget.download(image_url.strip())`

Comment: @Rakesh, just now I also identified the same. and i use image_filename = wget.download(image_url.rstrip()). and it is working. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the lines have a trailing `\n` character so you might want to strip the end of the string using `rstrip()` method.

```
for line in f:
    image_url = line.rstrip()    # Strips newline character at the end of line
    print(image_url)

    image_filename = wget.download(image_url)
    print('Image Successfully Downloaded:', image_url)
```